# Bi fold door pivot removals

Tags: doors

Top plastic pivot is broken in bi fold door how can I get it out? I can't use pliers not enough to get a grip

Comment: Show a picture.

Comment: If you had a picture we could be more sure of What you are looking at - as there are many types of units out there and yours might be different. Typically I would use a Wood Screw or lag bolt  like an easy out to run into the plastic and then pull it out. IF you have a hollow plastic pin - if the door is out of the track and you have access that is..

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're dealing with standard hardware inserts, as shown in the bottom row here. Simply grasp the shaft below the end device with a pliers and tap on the pliers with a hammer. It should pop out.

[image]

If you're not dealing with this type of hardware, please update your question with adequate information and/or photos.